# Correct time lag in regression

Tags: regression, time-series

Let's say you have two time series.  you know they are highly correlated with the right time lag.  Is there a function that's used to calculate the correct time lag, or do you just have to run a bunch of different regressions to find it?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021944/efficiency-in-time-series-regression-in-r-how-can-i-do-this-better

Comment: The [cross-correlation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation#Time_series_analysis) is often used for this purpose (in similar fashion to the ACF and PACF within-series), but to my recollection you usually want to  remove/account for dependence within-series first (certainly, they have to be stationary, but I think there's also some issues with stationary series, for example, if there's pseudo-cyclical behavior, which you can see even with AR(2), you might get apparent cross-correlation resulting from that). One of our time series experts will no doubt give better information